# TCPDF - Pass get parameter to HTML page

Tags: php, get, tcpdf, html-to-pdf

I've used TCPDF library to generate PDF from HTML. Here, In the URL there are few GET parameters and I have to pass those parameters to my html content,

Here  is the code sample,

Loading URL
http://localhost/test/index.php?name=Alex

index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'tcpdf_import.php';
// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->AddPage();

$html = file_get_contents('./content.php');
 
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
$pdf->Output('five-min-pdf.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

content.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TCPDF Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="divIdToPrint">
        <h3>Header 1</h4>
        <h4><?php $_GET['name']; ?></h4>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any suggestions how can I pass `'name'` parameter to html page?

Comment: `content.html` has PHP inside it, which won't render the URL `name` param you are referencing with $_GET.